# Getting position of a user in a mySql database

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the position of a specific user in a leaderboard for basketballScore. There is only one table in the database.
Here is the image of the database in mySQL

[image: Database image]

I imagine it would be something like this:

```
SELECT userID, SUM(points) as '`basketballScore`'

FROM user 

ORDER BY SUM(points) DESC
```

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: just an integer

Answer (score 0):

You need a `group by` clause:

```
select userID,
    SUM(score) as basketballScore
from user
group by userID
order by basketballScore desc
```

Also note that I reused the alias `basketballScore` in the `order by` clause.

If you need to create ranks, you can use user variables:

```
set @rank := 0;

select @rank := @rank + 1 as rank, 
    userID,
    SUM(score) as basketballScore
from user
group by userID
order by basketballScore desc
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I get this error though: Unknown column 'points' in 'field list'

Comment: @Pavol - I just modified your given query. If the column name is score, just use that. Updated the answer. Also added another query to generate score based ranks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the rank of a specific user by doing:

```
select 1 + count(*) as rank
from user u
where u.basketballScore > (select u2.basketballScore from user u2 where u2.userId = @userId);
```

Comment: I get "1" when i run this code: `select 1 + count(*) as rank
from user u
where u. basketballScore` >= (select `basketballScore` from user u2 where u.username=@a);`

Comment: I think it should be `>` instead of `>=`. 1 + number of users with a **higher** score.

Comment: Hi @PaulSpiegel it still returns 1

Comment: @Pavol - You need to replace `@userID` with the ID of the "specific user".

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I replaced it with a specific one and tried to change it to username as you can see above. It still returns 1

Comment: @Pavol . . . The subquery should be `u2.username`, not `u.username`.

Comment: Thank you all so much! It works now. I spent ages looking at it. Here is the final code if anyone is looking for it: select 1 + count(*) as rank
from user u
where u.basketballScore > (select u2.basketballScore from user u2 where u2.username = "pavol");